# vue selecting one checkbox is affecting other checkboxes

Tags: vue.js

I am working on menu-permissions using vue. I want assign "Edit", "create", "delete" on different menus. Now If I click on "create" checkbox of some menu, It is triggering other "create" checkboxes.

What I am trying is demonstrated on this [codepen](https://codepen.io/rezut/pen/OJZjMYw)

How can I assign separate functionalities to separate **menus**?

```js
console.clear();

// New VueJS instance
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    menus: [
      { id: 1, menuName: "Tech 1" },
      { id: 2, menuName: "Tech 2" },
      { id: 3, menuName: "Tech 3" }
    ],
    selectedActions: [],
    selectedMenu: [],
    selectedSubMenu: [],
    submenus: [
      { id: 1, menuId: 1, subMenuName: "architecture" },
      { id: 2, menuId: 1, subMenuName: "Electrical" },
      { id: 3, menuId: 1, subMenuName: "Electronics" },
      { id: 4, menuId: 2, subMenuName: "IEM" },
      { id: 5, menuId: 3, subMenuName: "CIVIL" }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    isUserInPreviousUsers() {
      return this.previousUsers.indexOf(this.userId) >= 0;
    },
    filteredProduct: function () {
      const app = this,
        menu = app.selectedMenu;

      if (menu.includes("0")) {
        return app.submenus;
      } else {
        return app.submenus.filter(function (item) {
          return menu.indexOf(item.menuId) >= 0;
        });
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setSelectedMenu: function (event, menu_id) {
      if (event.target.checked) {
        this.selectedMenu.push(menu_id);
      } else {
        var index = this.selectedMenu.indexOf(menu_id);
        this.selectedMenu.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- Include the library in the page -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.0-beta.1/dist/vue.js"></script>

<!-- App -->
<div id="app">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Menu</th>
        <th>Submenu</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="menu in menus" :key="menu.id">
        <td>
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" :value="menu.id" v-model="selectedMenu" />{{ menu.menuName }}
          </label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <ul>
            <li v-for="submenu in filteredProduct" :key="submenu.id" v-if="menu.id == submenu.menuId">

              <input type="checkbox" :value="submenu.id" v-model="selectedSubMenu" />
              <label>{{ submenu.subMenuName }} </label>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td class="permission-action">
          <label class="btn bg-success">
            <input type="checkbox" name="action[]" v-model="selectedActions" value="Create" />Create</label><br />
          <label class="btn bg-primary">
            <input type="checkbox" name="action[]" v-model="selectedActions" value="Edit" />Edit</label><br />
          <label class="btn bg-danger">
            <input type="checkbox" name="action[]" v-model="selectedActions" value="Delete" />Delete</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Probably because of this: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function + some other things.

Comment: I understand but It became very complex for me as I am new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like in the snippet below.

The only thing changed is the value attribute of the Create, Edit and Delete inputs. Change it to `:value="{name: 'Create', menu: index}"` and then read the object as per need.

[**Here is a JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/7oqarjg1/)

```js
console.clear();

// New VueJS instance
var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
      menus: [
        { id: 1, menuName: "Tech 1" },
        { id: 2, menuName: "Tech 2" },
        { id: 3, menuName: "Tech 3" }
      ],
      selectedActions: [],
      selectedMenu: [],
      selectedSubMenu: [],
      submenus: [
        { id: 1, menuId: 1, subMenuName: "architecture" },
        { id: 2, menuId: 1, subMenuName: "Electrical" },
        { id: 3, menuId: 1, subMenuName: "Electronics" },
        { id: 4, menuId: 2, subMenuName: "IEM" },
        { id: 5, menuId: 3, subMenuName: "CIVIL" }
      ]
    },
    computed: {
      isUserInPreviousUsers() {
        return this.previousUsers.indexOf(this.userId) >= 0;
      },
      filteredProduct: function () {
        const app = this,
          menu = app.selectedMenu;

        if (menu.includes("0")) {
          return app.submenus;
        } else {
          return app.submenus.filter(function (item) {
            return menu.indexOf(item.menuId) >= 0;
          });
        }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      setSelectedMenu: function (event, menu_id) {
        if (event.target.checked) {
          this.selectedMenu.push(menu_id);
        } else {
          var index = this.selectedMenu.indexOf(menu_id);
          this.selectedMenu.splice(index, 1);
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      selectedActions() {
        console.log(this.selectedActions)
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<!-- Include the library in the page -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.0-beta.1/dist/vue.js"></script>

<!-- App -->
<div id="app">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Menu</th>
        <th>Submenu</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(menu, index) in menus" :key="menu.id">
        <td>
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" :value="menu.id" v-model="selectedMenu" />{{ menu.menuName }}
          </label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <ul>
            <li v-for="submenu in filteredProduct" :key="submenu.id" v-if="menu.id == submenu.menuId">

              <input type="checkbox" :value="submenu.id" v-model="selectedSubMenu" />
              <label>{{ submenu.subMenuName }} </label>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td class="permission-action">
          <label class="btn bg-success">
            <input type="checkbox" name="action[]" v-model="selectedActions" :value="{name: 'Create', menu: index}" />Create</label><br />
          <label class="btn bg-primary">
            <input type="checkbox" name="action[]" v-model="selectedActions" :value="{name: 'Edit', menu: index}" />Edit</label><br />
          <label class="btn bg-danger">
            <input type="checkbox" name="action[]" v-model="selectedActions" :value="{name: 'Delete', menu: index}" />Delete</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: In the snippet it's still showing the error.

Comment: @16_018MD.REAZULHASANRAHI wait I came up with a better method. Just use objects as values like `:value="{name: 'Create', menu: index}"`

Comment: I don't understand your method. Can you please apply your method in the snippet?

Comment: @16_018MD.REAZULHASANRAHI done. Press the full page button on the snippet because the console becomes too large. In the console you can see the resulting array of objects from which you can read the value of each individual input, and to what "menu" it belongs (by index)